# siblings on select boxes is not working?

Tags: jquery, select, each, children, siblings

I want to make  option disabled if already selected in other  box.
For this I wrote a common class say 'my_select_class' for all  boxes and I am calling $('my_select_class').change() event the event is getting fired but the siblings loop of each other children '.my_select_class' is not working properly.

My code is:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">Member</label>
     <select class="form-control my_select_class" id="member0" name="member_list[0][id]" required="">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option> 
     </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">Role</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="member_list[0][p_role]" required="">
       <option value="">Select</option>
       -------------------------
       -------------------                                           
     </select>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="lopdisp1" style="display: block;">
    <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">Member</label>
     <select class="form-control my_select_class" id="member1" name="member_list[1][id]" required="">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option> 
     </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Role</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="member_list[1][p_role]" required="">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        -------------------------
        -------------------                                           
      </select>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="lopdisp2" style="display: block;">
   -------------------------
   -----------------------
  </div>
  <div id="lopdisp3" style="display: block;">
   -------------------------
   -----------------------
  </div>
```

My JS code is:

```
$(document).on('change', '.my_select_class', function(){
 var value = $(this).val();
 $(this).siblings('.my_select_class').children('option').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() === value ) {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').siblings().removeAttr('disabled');   
    }
 });
});
```

I want like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dZqEu/
Can Anyone please tell me whats wrong in my code. Thanks.

Comment: Your fiddle is completely different HTML and works fine. The code in your question will not work though, as the `.my_select_class` elements are not siblings...

Comment: That fiddle is just an example I want to achieve. If `.my_select_class` are not siblings then could you plz tell how to make changes to my HTML to work as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using multiple `id=member`, that is invalid HTML.

What I did is use the `data-*` attribute to group the selects. All that should interact with each other have the same `data-type`.

I commented the `role` selects out, while they have no options or values.

Please look at the comments in the JS code for clarification.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.my_select_class', function() {
  var type = $(this).data('type'),
      items = $('select[data-type="'+type+'"]');
      
  items.find('option').removeAttr('disabled');
  items.each(function() {
    items
      .not(this)
      .find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]')
      .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Member</label>
      <select class="form-control my_select_class" data-type="member" name="member_list[0][id]" required="">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option> 
     </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--div class="col-md-5">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">Role</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="member_list[0][p_role]" required="">
       <option value="">Select</option>
       -------------------------
       -------------------                                           
     </select>
   </div>
  </div-->
  <div id="lopdisp1" style="display: block;">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Member</label>
        <select class="form-control my_select_class" data-type="member" name="member_list[1][id]" required="">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option> 
     </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--div class="col-md-5">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">Role</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="member_list[1][p_role]" required="">
       <option value="">Select</option>
       -------------------------
       -------------------                                           
     </select>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div-->
    <div id="lopdisp1" style="display: block;">
      ------------------------- -----------------------
    </div>
```

## EDIT

I cleaned up all extra code that isn't needed, to make the code more understandalbe...

```js
$(document).on('change', '.my_select_class', function() {
  var type = $(this).data('type'),
      items = $('select[data-type="'+type+'"]');
      
  items.find('option').removeAttr('disabled');
  items.each(function() {
    items
      .not(this)
      .find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]')
      .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="control-label">Member</label>
<select class="form-control my_select_class" data-type="member" name="member_list[0][id]" required>
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">option1</option>
  <option value="2">option2</option>
  <option value="3">option3</option> 
</select>

<label class="control-label">Member</label>
<select class="form-control my_select_class" data-type="member" name="member_list[1][id]" required>
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">option1</option>
  <option value="2">option2</option>
  <option value="3">option3</option> 
</select>

<label class="control-label">Member</label>
<select class="form-control my_select_class" data-type="member" name="member_list[1][id]" required>
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">option1</option>
  <option value="2">option2</option>
  <option value="3">option3</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: First, Thanks for the quick reply. I will try your solution. I am not using multiple `id=member` while posting my question for hiding my data I just edited. I have edited my question again. Those are actually unique.

Comment: @prasadchinthala, okay, that is good. You can still use my solution and use the `data-type` attribute.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks @LinkinTED You are an amazing coder. Thanq once again.

Comment: There is a bug in the script that is: If I simply select all options one by one without selecting one option then those options which were just selected are getting disabled in other select boxes. Could you Plz fix this?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a JSFiddle, as this bug doesn't appear by me....

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply. Please first select all options one by one in the first `<select>` box before selecting other `<select>` boxes, here is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Luee8jx/5/

Comment: @prasadchinthala You are right, I updated my answer. It now loops all the `select` and disabled the option in the other `select`. Works with multiple `select` as well, see the last snippet with three `select`

Comment: yes it is working fine now, but I have a doubt that why JS variable "var value = $(this).val();" is not working inside the loop as `items.each(function(){ items.not(this).find('option[value="'+value+'"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); });` Only `$(this).val()` is working inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your my_select_class doesn't have siblings with my_select_class. You have to go up the DOM and then find the my_select_class.